# Method sum values of same type in ArrayList in java

Tags: java, eclipse

**//I wrote the method it have 3 types of workers:
Manager, Owner and Worker**

```
public static int costByType() {
        ArrayList<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();
        String type;
        int cost = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter type of worker[M/m][W/w][O/o] for finish enter [F/f]:");
        type = s.nextLine();
        while(!type.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
            for (Worker w : workers) {
                if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("M")) {
                    cost += ((Manager) w).getSalary() + ((Manager) w).getBonus();
                } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("W")) {
                    cost += ((Worker) w).getSalary();
                } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("O")) {
                    cost += ((Owner) w).getSalary() + ((Owner) w).getBonus() +Owner.BASE;
                }
            }

        }

        return cost;    

    }
```

**//The while loop run the array list and find the type of worker and sum the values**
The code not return anything. Instead it do the char scan in loop while again and again****
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That part

```
System.out.println("Enter type of worker[M/m][W/w][O/o] for finish enter [F/f]:");
type = s.nextLine();
```

needs to go **into** your loop!

When you expect the user to enter values multiple times then it does not help to fetch his input just once!

Comment: if I put it inside it not recognize the type in while condition     while(!type.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {

Answer (score 0):

This is because the your ArrayList "workers" was queried but never updated. In other words your ArrayList doesn't contain any worker in it.

Fill worker in the workers list first, pass it to the function like costByType(workers) instead of creating it inside your function and then use do while loop instead. something like this.

```
         do {
            System.out.println("Enter type of worker[M/m][W/w][O/o] for finish enter [F/f]:");
            type = src.nextLine();
            for (Worker w : workers) {
                if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("M")) {
                    cost += ((Manager) w).getSalary() + ((Manager) w).getBonus();
                } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("W")) {
                    cost += ((Worker) w).getSalary();
                } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("O")) {
                    cost += ((Owner) w).getSalary() + ((Owner) w).getBonus() +Owner.BASE;
                }
            }

        } while(!type.equalsIgnoreCase("F"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**i changed the code:**

public static int costByType(ArrayList<Worker> workers) {
        String type;
        int cost = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter type of worker[M/m][W/w][O/o] for finish enter [F/f]:");
            type = s.nextLine();
            for (Worker w : workers) {
                if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("M") && (w instanceof Manager)) {
                    cost += ((Manager) w).getSalary() + ((Manager) w).getBonus();
                } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("W") && (w instanceof Worker)) {
                    cost += ((Worker) w).getSalary();
                } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("O") && (w instanceof Owner)) {
                    cost += ((Owner) w).getSalary() + ((Owner) w).getBonus() + Owner.BASE;
                }

            }
            return cost;

        } while (!type.equalsIgnoreCase("F"));
    }
```

***//now it not loop after it show the cost. It should run again and show cost until String is f***